# Why isn't reactive the data with props in this situation?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have two componets beside the `App.vue` component, the `Rooms.vue` and the `Desks.vue`.
When I click on the on one of the swiper element in the `Rooms.vue` component, then opens the Desks.vue component and emits the `room` object to `App.vue`, and from there is passed down into the `Desks.vue` as prop. In the `Desks.vue` the prop `room` is reactive, so when I click on another swiper element, the `prop.room` is changed. However, in the `reserveData` the `room` property doesn't change.

Can you tell me why isn't reactive the `room` prop in the `reserveData` object?

App.vue

```
const room = ref(null)
const openRoom = (rm) => {
  room.value = rm
  console.log(room.value)
}

const closeRoom = () => {
  room.value = null
}

</script>

<template>
  <Header title="Friendbook"/>
  <Rooms @openRoom="openRoom" :room="room"/>
  <transition>
    <Desks v-if="room" :room="room" @closeRoom="closeRoom"/>
  </transition>
</template>
```

Rooms.vue

```
const emit = defineEmits(['openRoom'])
const props = defineProps({room: Object})

const roomStore = useRoomStore()

const onSwiper = (swiper) => {
  // console.log(swiper)
};

const onSlideChange = () => {
  // console.log('slide change');
};


const activeRoomIdx = ref(null)

const clickOnRoom = (room, idx) => {
  activeRoomIdx.value = idx;
  emit('openRoom', room);
}

watch(() => props.room, (newVal, oldVal) => {
  if (!newVal) {
    activeRoomIdx.value = null
  }
})

</script>

<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Rooms</h3>
    <div class="rooms-container">
      <span class="swiper-button prev"></span>
      <swiper
          :modules="swiperOptions.modules"
          :space-between="12"
          @swiper="onSwiper"
          @slideChange="onSlideChange"
          :navigation="swiperOptions.navigation"
          :breakpoints="swiperOptions.breakpoints"
      >
        <swiper-slide v-for="(room, idx) in roomStore.rooms">
          <div class="room-container" :class="{active: activeRoomIdx === idx}" @click="clickOnRoom(room, idx)">
            {{ room.name }}
          </div>
        </swiper-slide>
      </swiper>
      <span class="swiper-button next"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Desks.vue

```
const props = defineProps({
  room: Object,
})

const {room} = toRefs(props)

defineEmits(['closeRoom'])


const employeeStore = useEmployeeStore()
const roomStore = useRoomStore()
const reserveData = reactive({
  employee: false,
  date: false,
  room: room.value.name,
  chosenDesk: false
})

const attrs = ref([])

const onDateChange = (range) => {
  console.log(range)
  console.log('hello')
}

const range = ref({start: new Date(new Date().getTime() -86400000), end: new Date(new Date().getTime() -86400000)})
const error = ref(false)

const makeDate = (date) => {
  let day = date.getUTCDate();
  let month = date.getUTCMonth() + 1;
  let year = date.getUTCFullYear();
  if (day < 10) {
    day = `0${day}`
  }
  if (month < 10) {
    month = `0${month}`
  }
  return `${day}-${month}-${year}`
}

const choseDesk = (newDesk) => {
  reserveData.chosenDesk = newDesk.name
  const desks = roomStore.rooms.find(room => room.name === props.room.name).desks
  const currDeskReserves = desks.find(desk => desk.name === newDesk.name).reserved
  attrs.value = currDeskReserves.map(cdr => {
    return {
      dot: 'red',
      popover: {
        label: cdr.person,
        visibility: 'hover',
        hideIndicator: false,
      },
      ...cdr
    }
  })
}

watch(() => range.value, (newVal, oldVal) => {
  reserveData.date = newVal
})

</script>

<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>{{ room.name }} Desks</h3>
    <div class="container-wrapper">

      <div class="desks-container">
        <div class="desk" :class="{active: reserveData.chosenDesk === desk.name}" @click="choseDesk(desk)"
             v-for="desk in room.desks">
          {{ desk.name }}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="inputs-container">
        <select name="employees" id="employees" @change="(e) => reserveData.employee = e.target.value">
          <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Für:</option>
          <option v-for="employee in employeeStore.employees" :key="employee" :value="employee">{{ employee }}</option>
        </select>
        <div class="from-to-container">
          <label for=""><span>Von:</span><input :value="makeDate(range.start)" type="text" id="from" disabled></label>
          <label for=""><span>Bis:</span><input :value="makeDate(range.end)" type="text" id="to" disabled></label>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons-container">
          <div v-if="error" class="error-message">Some days are reserved</div>
          <div class="buttons">
            <input class="small" type="button" value="Buchen" @click="roomStore.addNewReserve(reserveData)">
            <input v-if="error" class="small secondary" type="button" value="Abbrechen">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="calendar-container">
        <VDatePicker
            @input="onDateChange"
            v-model.range="range"
            locale="de"
            trim-weeks
            :min-date="new Date()"
            color="indigo"
            :first-day-of-week="2"
            :attributes="attrs"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="close-button" @click="$emit('closeRoom')"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you initialize `reserveData`, you set the `room` property to the name of your current `room` ref:

```
const reserveData = reactive({
  room: room.value.name,
  ...
})
```

This is a value, not the reactive object. So the `room` prop is now a string, and it will not change when your `room` ref changes.

---

A simple way to fix it is to put the ref into `reserverData` and extract the room name from there, i.e. `reserveData.room.name`. Note that in Vue 3.3, you have to use `toRef()` with a function if you use it on props:

```
const room = toRef(() => props.room) // in Vue 3.3
const reserveData = reactive({
  room: room,
  ...
})
```

A better solution is probably to use a watcher that updates `reserveData` when the room changes:

```
watch(room, () => reserveData.room = room.value.name)
```

Comment: Thanks! Also with the `room: room` didn't work, but with `room: room.value` works as it should!

Comment: Hmm, why is it not working with `room: room`? You can use `room.value`, but that means that you are again using the (non-reactive) object. When you change room, it should not update, since `room.value` still points to the initial object. Are you sure that works?

Comment: nah, it doesn't work neither with `room: room`  or with `room: room.value`. With `room: room` the room property will be `undefined (Ref)`

Comment: Yeah, use the watcher, it is the cleanest solution

Comment: @tg22a Means that something is wrong on your side. With `room: room`, reserveData.room should be exactly what you see with `console.log(room.value)`

Comment: @MoritzRingler I don't know why is that, for example with `room: room.value` I got the correct value, but does't change, buth with `room: room` I got the undifened(Ref), really strange. With `watch` it works.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out, the issue comes from `toRef`, in Vue 3.3, if you use it on a prop, you have to do `toRef(() => prop.room)`. This works when I try it out. It's those nitty-gritty details with ref arithmetic that make me prefer the watcher...

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your `reserveData` object as a computed value.

The `room` property of `reserveData` object is not reactive because it's defined only once when component was rendered. If you want to keep there an actual value from a prop, the `reserveData` object must be computed

```
const reserveData = computed(() => ({
  employee: false,
  date: false,
  room: room.value.name,
  chosenDesk: false
}))
```

Also, instead of making `reserveData` computed, you can make a **watch** function that will track the prop `room` change and set a new value for `room` in the `reserveData` object.

Comment: Using a computed value would reset all the other values when the room changes, right? Might be desired or a problem. +1 anyway

Comment: Thanks, the watch method works, but computed not really. Just as @MoritzRingler mentioned, it resets the data, so the rest of the property doesn't change.

Comment: Yep, my bad about computed, of course it would reset other values. It can be solved using **watch**, not **computed**